# How to check annotation before loading class?

Tags: java, annotations, classloader

I have my own class loader. I'd like to load class only if it has some specified annotation.

How to check annotation before loading the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example of class annotation:

```
@SomeAnnotation(name="someName", value="someValue")
public class Meta {}
```

The `Meta` definition:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface SomeAnnotation {
    public String name();
    public String value();
}
```

Access to the class annotation and load class:

```
Class clazz = Meta.class;
ClassLoader classLoader = clazz.getClassLoader();    
Annotation annotation = clazz.getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class);
if (annotation instanceof SomeAnnotation) {
   classLoader.loadClass("Meta");
}
```